# Use of pointers in multi dimensional arrays in C

Tags: c

I have this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    printf("\  Elements of an array with their address\n");
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        printf("%8u",&a[0][0]+i);
        printf("[%d]",*(&a[0][0]+i));
        if(i==2 || i==5)
            printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Can you please explain why  `(if(i==2 || i==5)` is used , I am really confused in this step.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: The `printf("\n")` is just to give you a nice 3x3 output. Easily verified with a little inspection or just running the program. :) If that's your only question, then the title of your post is a little off.

Comment: It probably would have been clearer as `if (i % 3 == 2) printf("\n");` (or `putchar('\n');`). Also, treating a 2D array as if it were a 1D array is very likely to work, but strictly speaking it's undefined behavior. But that's not what you asked about, so ...

Comment: Also, `%8u` is *not* the correct format for printing an address. `printf("%8u",&a[0][0]+i);` should be `printf("%p", (void*)&a[0][0]+i);` -- though that may not align the columns as nicely, since the output for `%p` is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 3):

The array is 0-indexed, so 2 and 5 are the spots before each sub-array starts, so it puts a line break before outputting them.

```
    {{1,2,3} , {4,5,6} , {7,8,9}};
 i=0--^   ^--i=2    ^--i=5
```

output looks something like this:

```
Elements of an array with their address
3021239472[1]3021239476[2]3021239480[3]
3021239484[4]3021239488[5]3021239492[6]
3021239496[7]3021239500[8]3021239504[9]
```

Notice each dimension of the array has its own line.

(Memory addresses may vary)

Comment: And it would be a good idea to have a newline at the end, so adding `|| i == 8` to the condition would be good, or use `if (i % 3 == 2)` as the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain this code to you, first, because you must first understand the program to reason a specific thing.

Here though for the humans, the array is in 2 dimensional matrix format of ( 3 X 3), for the computer address, it is of continuous memory location. Say, for example when it is starts from address 1000 (Though original implementation will have hexadecimal address system), Then  the 9 elements are stored in next 36 bytes, such that each integer takes 4 bytes.

Now in you code, you are traversing from 1 to 9 integer, by incrementing from the first address. Instead of that, you could well use an integer pointer for that.

Though it is in contiguous memory space, for humans we need a matrix kind of output, because in that representation only we have understood things of 2D array. So, for that we need `break-ups` in the continuos array. For that in here `row size` is `3`. So since the index starts from zero, we `break` output format by a new line ('\n') for every third element.

Hence after  `(0,1, 2 <- Here we have breakup say )` 
 
         Then   `(3,4, 5 <- Here too )`